# How to draw Left Arrow in this Vibrating String with tikzpicture?

Tags: arrows

I am trying to make the green left arrow pointed to the left and the tail will be on the most left blue string, the right green arrow pointed to the right is already correct.

The problem is, I can't really put the left green arrow or point it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Waves
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % for arrow size
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head

\colorlet{xcol}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{vcol}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!70!black}
\tikzstyle{vvec}=[->,vcol,very thick,line cap=round]
\tikzstyle{myarr}=[-{Latex[length=3,width=2]},myred]
\def\tick#1#2{\draw[thick] (#1) ++ (#2:0.1) --++ (#2-180:0.2)}
\def\xpeak#1{{(0.21+#1)*\xmax}}
\def\wave#1{
    \coordinate (F) at (\xpeak{#1},\ypeak);
    \draw[very thick,xcol]
    (-0.08*\xmax,0) -- ({(0.06+#1)*\xmax},0) to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.5] (F)
    to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.6]++ (0.25*\xmax,-\ypeak) -- (0.94*\xmax,0);
}
\begin{document}
    \section{Vibrating string}
    % WAVE t = 0
    \def\xmax{6.8}
    \def\ymax{1.3}
    \def\A{0.82*\ymax}
    \def\v{0.10*\xmax}
    \def\lamb{0.4*\xmax} % wavelength (radians)
    \def\om{360/(\lamb)}  % omega (degrees)
    \def\xa{0.38*\lamb}   % point x_1
    \def\xb{1.38*\lamb}   % point x_2
    \def\ya{\A*sin(\om*\xa)} % point y_1 = y_2
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->,thick] (-0.2*\ymax,0) -- (1.05*\xmax,0) node[right=4,below left=1] {$x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-\ymax) -- (0,1.08*\ymax) node[left=1] {$y$};
        \draw[xcol,very thick,samples=100,smooth,variable=\x,domain=0:\xmax]
        plot(\x,{\A*sin(\om*\x)});
        \draw[dashed]
        (0,\A) --++ (1.35*\lamb,0)
        (0,-\A) --++ (1.87*\lamb,0);
        \draw[<->] (\xa, 1.24*\A) -- (\xb, 1.24*\A) node[midway,fill=white,inner sep=1] {$\lambda$};
        \tick{0,\A}{0} node[scale=0.9,left=-1] {$A$};
        \tick{0,-\A}{0} node[scale=0.9,left=-1] {$-A$};
        \draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(6:2.5*\A) --++ (\v,0) node[above=1,right=-1] {$T$};
        \draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(-8:-2.5*\A) --++ (\v,0) node[above=1,left=1] {$T$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice question attracts attention +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt,scale=2]
        \fill[gray!10] (-0.5,-1.5) rectangle (6,1.8); % prepara il colore di fondo
        \draw [->,style=thick] (-.2,0) -- (5.2,0) node[pos=1,right] {distance}; 
        \draw [->,style=thick] (0,-1.30) -- (0,1.3) node[pos=1,above] {displacement}; 
        \draw[thick] (-0.05,1) to (0.05,1) node[black,left] at (-0.05,1) {$+A$};
        \draw[thick] (-0.05,-1) to (0.05,-1) node[black,left] at (-0.05,-1) {$-A$};
        \draw [cyan,domain=0:5, samples=100] plot (\x, {sin(180*\x)});
        \draw[<-,line width=1pt] (.5,1.3)--(1.1,1.3);
        \draw[->,line width=1pt] (1.9,1.3)--(2.5,1.3);
        \draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (.5,0)--(.5,1.3);
        \draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (2.5,0)--(2.5,1.3);
        \draw[<-,line width=1pt] (1.5,-1.3)--(2.1,-1.3);
        \draw[->,line width=1pt] (2.9,-1.3)--(3.5,-1.3);
        \draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (1.5,0)--(1.5,-1.3);
        \draw[dotted,line width=.5pt] (3.5,0)--(3.5,-1.3);
        \draw [red] node[fill=white] at (1.5,1.3) {wave length, $\lambda$};
        \draw [red] node[fill=white] at (2.5,-1.3) {wave length, $\lambda$};
        \draw[<->,dotted,line width=.5pt] (.5,0)--(.5,1);
        \draw[green,line width=2,-latex] (.1,{sin(18)})--(-.3,{sin(18)}) node[left] () {$T$};
        \draw[green,line width=2,-latex] (4.9,{sin(18)})--(5.3,{sin(18)}) node[right] () {$T$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Alright, great thanks!

Comment: @js bibra Spelling changed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**For the green arrow pointing left**

The syntax to change is the following line

```
\draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(-8:-2.5*\A) --++ (\v,0) node[above=1,left=1] {$T$};
```

which needs to be amended as

```
\draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(-5:-3.7*\A) --++ (-\v,0) node[above=1,left=1] {$T$};
```

**For the alignment of lambda with the peaks of the sin curve**

changed the definition of the point `\xa` and point `\xb`
from the existing

```
\def\xa{0.38*\lamb}   % point x_1
\def\xb{1.38*\lamb}   % point x_2
```

to the following

```
\def\xa{0.24*\lamb}   % point x_1
\def\xb{1.24*\lamb}   % point x_2
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Waves
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % for arrow size
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head

\colorlet{xcol}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{vcol}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!70!black}
\tikzstyle{vvec}=[->,vcol,very thick,line cap=round]
\tikzstyle{myarr}=[-{Latex[length=3,width=2]},myred]
\def\tick#1#2{\draw[thick] (#1) ++ (#2:0.1) --++ (#2-180:0.2)}
\def\xpeak#1{{(0.21+#1)*\xmax}}
\def\wave#1{
    \coordinate (F) at (\xpeak{#1},\ypeak);
    \draw[very thick,xcol]
    (-0.08*\xmax,0) -- ({(0.06+#1)*\xmax},0) to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.5] (F)
    to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.6]++ (0.25*\xmax,-\ypeak) -- (0.94*\xmax,0);
}
\begin{document}
    \section{Vibrating string}
    % WAVE t = 0
    \def\xmax{6.8}
    \def\ymax{1.3}
    \def\A{0.82*\ymax}
    \def\v{0.10*\xmax}
    \def\lamb{0.4*\xmax} % wavelength (radians)
    \def\om{360/(\lamb)}  % omega (degrees)
    \def\xa{0.24*\lamb}   % point x_1
    \def\xb{1.24*\lamb}   % point x_2
    \def\ya{\A*sin(\om*\xa)} % point y_1 = y_2
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->,thick] (-0.2*\ymax,0) -- (1.05*\xmax,0) node[right=4,below left=1] {$x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-\ymax) -- (0,1.08*\ymax) node[left=1] {$y$};
        \draw[xcol,very thick,samples=100,smooth,variable=\x,domain=0:\xmax]
        plot(\x,{\A*sin(\om*\x)});
        \draw[dashed]
        (0,\A) --++ (1.35*\lamb,0)
        (0,-\A) --++ (1.87*\lamb,0);
        \draw[<->] (\xa, 1.24*\A) -- (\xb, 1.24*\A) node[midway,fill=white,inner sep=1] {$\lambda$};
        \tick{0,\A}{0} node[scale=0.9,left=-1] {$A$};
        \tick{0,-\A}{0} node[scale=0.9,left=-1] {$-A$};
        \draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(6:2.5*\A) --++ (\v,0) node[above=1,right=-1] {$T$};
        \draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(-5:-3.7*\A) --++ (-\v,0) node[above=1,left=1] {$T$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Though the `lambda` has been given a white background however that would not be visible since the default background is already white for the `paper/article` - therefore the need to give a `grey` background to the `sin wave` does occur - by including the following

```
   \fill[gray!10] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (8,1.8);
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Waves
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % for arrow size
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head

\colorlet{xcol}{blue!70!black}
\colorlet{vcol}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myred}{red!70!black}
\tikzstyle{vvec}=[->,vcol,very thick,line cap=round]
\tikzstyle{myarr}=[-{Latex[length=3,width=2]},myred]
\def\tick#1#2{\draw[thick] (#1) ++ (#2:0.1) --++ (#2-180:0.2)}
\def\xpeak#1{{(0.21+#1)*\xmax}}
\def\wave#1{
    \coordinate (F) at (\xpeak{#1},\ypeak);
    \draw[very thick,xcol]
    (-0.08*\xmax,0) -- ({(0.06+#1)*\xmax},0) to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.5] (F)
    to[out=0,in=180,looseness=0.6]++ (0.25*\xmax,-\ypeak) -- (0.94*\xmax,0);
}
\begin{document}
    \section{Vibrating string}
    % WAVE t = 0
    \def\xmax{6.8}
    \def\ymax{1.3}
    \def\A{0.82*\ymax}
    \def\v{0.10*\xmax}
    \def\lamb{0.4*\xmax} % wavelength (radians)
    \def\om{360/(\lamb)}  % omega (degrees)
    \def\xa{0.24*\lamb}   % point x_1
    \def\xb{1.24*\lamb}   % point x_2
    \def\ya{\A*sin(\om*\xa)} % point y_1 = y_2
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[gray!10] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (8,1.8);
        \draw[->,thick] (-0.2*\ymax,0) -- (1.05*\xmax,0) node[right=4,below left=1] {$x$};
        \draw[->,thick] (0,-\ymax) -- (0,1.08*\ymax) node[left=1] {$y$};
        \draw[xcol,very thick,samples=100,smooth,variable=\x,domain=0:\xmax]
        plot(\x,{\A*sin(\om*\x)});
        \draw[dashed]
        (0,\A) --++ (1.35*\lamb,0)
        (0,-\A) --++ (1.87*\lamb,0);
        \draw[<->] (\xa, 1.24*\A) -- (\xb, 1.24*\A) node[midway,fill=white,inner sep=1] {$\lambda$};
        \tick{0,\A}{0} node[scale=0.9,left=-1] {$A$};
        \tick{0,-\A}{0} node[scale=0.9,left=-1] {$-A$};
        \draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(6:2.5*\A) --++ (\v,0) node[above=1,right=-1] {$T$};
        \draw[vvec] (1.5*\lamb,0)++(-5:-3.7*\A) --++ (-\v,0) node[above=1,left=1] {$T$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the output

[image]